# Coverage show test get_serializer_class as untested

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-unittest, django-testing, django-tests

Use coverage  to show what have to be covered by tests drf views. And coverage show that all view is tested ok (cover by unittest + dango client API)

But coverage shows that this part need to be covered:

```
def get_serializer_class(self): 
    return self.serializer_class `
```

I think that that code possible to delete as it useless (it is not my code):)

Any idea how to cover that past of code in `GenericAPIView`? Thx for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to specify the serializer class:

1. First approach is to set the `serializer_class` attribute in your class.
2. Second approach is to override the `get_serializer_class()`method.

If you already added the `serializer_class` attribute in your class (first approach) then the `get_serializer_class()` is definitely useless.

This is the example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from myapp.serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework import generics

class UserList(generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

In most situations you should use the first approach because usually you will need only one serializer for your API view. Second approach is useful for dynamic behavior, such as using different serializers for read and write operations, or providing different serializers to different types of users.

Example:

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.user.is_staff:
        return StaffSerializer
    return BasicSerializer
```